# Adding the diagonal of a 4x4 array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, addition

I'm trying to add the diagonal of a 4x4 matrix that the user inputs, and when I run the program,
my line with the addition of all 4 values in the array gives an error.

Am I not adding them correctly?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Set_9_P7_2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double x;
        double[][] sumMajorDiagnol = new double[4][4];

        System.out.println("Enter a 4-by-4 matrix row by row:");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         for (int i = 0; i < sumMajorDiagnol.length; i++) {
             for (int j = 0; j < sumMajorDiagnol.length; j++) {
                 sumMajorDiagnol[i][j] = input.nextDouble();                 
             }
         }

         x = sumMajorDiagnol[1][1] + sumMajorDiagnol[2][2] + sumMajorDiagnol[3][3] + sumMajorDiagnol[4][4];

         System.out.println("The sum of the elements in the major diagnal is " + x);

    }

}
```

Instead of it printing the actual answer 4, I get this error:

```
    Enter a 4-by-4 matrix row by row:
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at Set_9_P7_2.main(Set_9_P7_2.java:21)
```

which points to this line:

```
x = sumMajorDiagnol[1][1] + sumMajorDiagnol[2][2] + sumMajorDiagnol[3][3] + sumMajorDiagnol[4][4];
```

Is this not how you're supposed to add them?

Answer (score 2):

The indices of the diagonal should be from `[0][0]` to `[3][3]`. And it would make more sense to use a for loop instead of writing them down explicitly :

```
double sum=0;
for (int i=0;i<sumMajorDiagnol.length;i++)
   sum+=sumMajorDiagnol[i][i];
```

Comment: Thanks man, I'll close this question once the time ends. Could you explain why a loop would make more sense? I'm new to java.

Comment: @SamShaheen a loop has the advantage of having the same code work for any dimention of the 2-d array.

Comment: If I wanted to make it add the entire matrix as a whole instead of just the diagonal, what would be the best way? @eran

Comment: @SamShaheen If you mean summing all the elements of the matrix, a nested loop would do the job (similar to the loop used to fill the 2d array).

Answer (score 0):

```
x = sumMajorDiagnol[1][1] + sumMajorDiagnol[2][2] + sumMajorDiagnol[3][3] + sumMajorDiagnol[4][4]
```

change to:

```
x = sumMajorDiagnol[0][0] + sumMajorDiagnol[1][1] + sumMajorDiagnol[2][2] + sumMajorDiagnol[3][3]
```

Or simply:

```
for(int i=0; i<sumMajorDiagnol.length; i++)
    x += sumMajorDiagnol[i][i];
```

Your array of size 4, the index ranges from 0-3. Not 1-4.

Answer (score 0):

To you code you can add

```
double x = 0;
```

and the following inside the two for loops:

```
if(i == j) {
  x += sumMajorDiagnol[i][j]
}
```

This way you will get the result as a bonus after traversing your two loops.

Your current code is failing because arrays start at zero and accessing an array of length 4 at index 4 means you are accessing it out of its bounds.